# Replace all occurencis of a substring except from strings between "

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have this code which replaced all the occurences of a certain substring inside the string code.

```
while (codecall= code.indexOf(mname) != -1) {
      position= codecall;
      code= code.replace(mname, "teach_subfun");
      i--;
}
```

This works good to me except the fact that the string code is actually representing some Javascript code I have to evaluate. Let's take an example of my problem. Let's say these are the variables values:

```
mname= "foo";
code= "document.write ('this foo must not be replaced'); foo (n);";
```

What i get with my code is:

```
mname= "foo";
code= "document.write ('this teach_subfun must not be replaced'); teach_subfun (n);";
```

What I'd like to obtain is:

```
mname= "foo";
code= "document.write ('this foo must not be replaced'); teach_subfun(n);";
```

is there a simple way to do it? maybe with RegExp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your code is well formatted *(correct number of quotes)*:

[**Demo at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/7R3DT/)

```
mnameA = /foo/g;
mnameB = "teach_subfun";
code= "document.write ('this foo must not be replaced'); foo(n);";

codeRep = code.split(/'|"/).map(function (e, i){
    return i % 2 ? e : e.replace(mnameA, mnameB);
}).join("");
```

**How does this works:**

If you split by `"`, strings will by always at the odd indexes (`i % 2 == 1`) of the generated array *(unless your code starts with a string)*, so the map function is going to replace all the foo's (`/foo/g`, *g is for all*) within each even element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way would be to not only look for `foo` but for `foo (` or even for `; foo (` and then replace it accordingly:

```
code.replace(mname, "; teach_subfun (");
```

Comment: I think This is not actual answer for OP's question. This is just an example given by him.